# How can we explain $e^{\pi}-\pi\approx20$?

Tags: geometry, inequality, exponential-function, pi, geometric-inequalities

Using a calculator we can easily check that $$\color{Green}{e^{\pi}-\pi}=19.999\cdots\color{Green}{\approx 20}$$
[This article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AlmostInteger.html) and [this one](https://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCwQFjACahUKEwjE5qauza3IAhWFco4KHWEKDV8&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FMathematical_coincidence&usg=AFQjCNGGNmoeK--lo9hiS9HxpESy4JPAaA) provides some details about this almost near identity, but no explanation. My question is :

> **Can we obtain the above almost equality geometrically?**

Add: Let me add more details to address the issues pointed some people in the comments section. As I think both numbers $\pi$ and $e$ are very geometric and their appearance in some unexpected places is due to this geometric nature. Also, here by geometry, I do not mean just Euclidean geometry (or ruler and compass construction), but in the inclusion sense.

Secondly, consider the graphs of functions $y=e^x$ and $y=x+20.$ We can compute their exact intersection points of them using [Lambert W function,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) and approximately they are $x=-19.99999\cdots$ and $x=3.1416\cdots.$ One of these numbers almost indistinguishable from $-20$ and the other is very close to $\pi.$ How can we explain this unreasonable result?

Comment: The first source you quoted states but no satisfying explanation as to "why" $e^{\pi}-\pi \approx 20$ is true has yet been discovered". Are you asking there are any progress in this "open" problem or what?

Comment: Why on earth should you expect a geometric explanation of the fact that $\sum_{j=2}^{\infty} \frac{\pi^{j}}{j!}$ is close to $19$ (it's not that close in any case)?

Comment: [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1103/409) shows a geometric interpretation for the terms of the power series for sine and cosine; consequently, $e^\theta$ is simply the total length of the polygonal spiral $P_0P_1P_2P_3\dots$. I don't see an obvious connection between the $e^\pi$ spiral and $20$, but that could just be a failure of imagination on my part. It might be worth noting that the not-very-good approximation $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}\approx \pi$ [has a geometric "explanation"](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/702053/409), so this question isn't completely unreasonable.

Comment: The point for that $\sqrt2+\sqrt3$ is that both of them are "constructible" (is that a word?). Personally I don't know a geometrical approximation of $e$, let alone $e^\pi$.

Comment: Seems unlikely that a pure geometric solution can be found, as there is no ruler and compass construction for the exponential. The number $e$ itself doesn't seem to mate well with geometry. (And by the way, we have no explanation at all regarding the quasi-equality.)

Comment: @YvesDaoust: That's true. But I hope there should be an approach using trigonometry, complex numbers or in another form.

Comment: @Nilan: you should rephrase your question, focusing on geometry caused its closing.

Comment: @YvesDaoust "you should rephrase your question, focusing on geometry caused its closing." I have mixed feelings about your comment.  I agree that it caused the query to be closed; and I certainly feel that the question is *overbroad*.  However, the core of the question is its focus on geometry and I (for one) would have trouble identifying a (narrow) sub-topic in geometry for the question to focus on.

Comment: @user2661923: what makes you think that $e$ is tractable by geometry ? (and plays an important role ???)

Comment: @YvesDaoust: $e$ is the unique real number such that the tangent to the graph (of the exponential) $y=e^x$ at $x=0$ is $1.$ To me it is a very geometric property.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Actually, being totally ignorant in the field, it wouldn't surprise me if $e$ was or was not tractable by geometry.  However, consider the question from the OP's perspective.  He was **not** asserting that there is a relation between $e$ and geometry.  Instead, he was *asking* if one existed.  Seems like a very reasonable and interesting *question to ask*.

Comment: @user2661923: are you kidding ? "Also we know that both $\pi$ and $e$ plays an important role in geometry." Do you deny that the OP wrote this ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Very good point.  I blind-spot glossed over that portion of his query, focusing only on the question in bold print.

Comment: @user2661923: $\pi$ cannot be constructed by compass and ruler. I have no idea of how $e$ could be constructed, and even less $e^\pi$. And showing that a quantity is a good approximation of another "geometrically" does not seem obvious. The OP is throwing a random request with no serious consideration of feasibility and wrong assumptions. I fail to see in what way this question would be interesting.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: I don't see why the word "geometry" means just "compass and ruler type constructions" to most people. I add few more lines to my question to make it clear.

Comment: I'm not an expert in this area but, perhaps you can get some inspiration From Heegner numbers and Ramanujan's constant, which have *algebraic* reasons for why they're close to integers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heegner_number

Comment: @Bumblebee: the Lambert function belongs to calculus. It is a wrong point of view to consider that the graph of a transcendental function is "geometry".

Comment: I see no reason to expect any special meaning behind this... strange occurrences happen all the time and it is human nature to focus on those strange occurrences and attempt to assign meaning to them... however there are flukes and coincidences all over the place.  Had this one not occurred then you would be asking about whatever other coincidence you had come across was, like some $\varphi^{\sqrt{2}}\approx 2$.  If there was strict equality, then perhaps I would be inclined to believe there to be some tangible reason/connection, but merely approximately?  Nah...

Comment: @JMoravitz: take a few mathematical constants, a few naturals, and form expressions with the arithmetic operations. The probability of "interesting" coincidences will increase with the number of constants and length of the expressions. A dumb computer program *will* find them. All these are indeed *pseudo*coincidences. You can find as many as you want, and as accurate as you want.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: So you don't see things like differential geometry as a part of geometry?

Comment: @Bumblebee: no, as applied calculus. I am not even sure that it requires the Euclidean axiomatics.

Comment: @JMoravitz: Yes, it is true that equalities are more interesting than approximation. But it is wrong to think that almost equalities are not important. There is a whole story and very interesting mathematics behind Ramanujan Constant. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4544/why-is-e-pi-sqrt163-almost-an-integer) and [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RamanujanConstant.html)

Comment: @YvesDaoust: So, what are your boundaries of "Geometry"? BTW according to modern standard there are holes in Euclid's presentation, and peoples now use either  Hilbert's axioms or Birkhoff's axioms, though I am not familiar with theses formulations.

Comment: @Bumblebee: sterile discussion. Next time enter an explicit question.

Comment: It looks like this question is a duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/724872/why-is-e-pi-pi-so-close-to-20